# AngularJS - http get response (JSON Array) and display in html

Tags: java, angularjs, arrays, json, servlets

I've created a servlet in Java that displays an array using;

```
    printWriter.println(jsonarray);
```

And the array shows up on the servlet page, but that's where the fun stops. I want to display the array as a table on a webpage using AngularJS, which I have no prior experience with. But I can't get the array to show on the webpage let alone display it as a table

HTML

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">{{myArray}}</div>
```

AngularJS

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myController", function($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.recipes = null;
    $scope.message = null;
    $scope.filterString = '';
    $scope.sortByName = false;
    $scope.sortOrder = '';
    $scope.setSortOrder = function()
    {
        if($scope.sortByName)
        {
            $scope.sortOrder = 'name';
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.sortOrder = '';
        }
    }


    var connection = $http(
    {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/students'
    })


    .then(function(response)
    {
        $scope.myArray = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function(response)
    {
        // It is OK not to take any action here because it would be
        // clear to the user if the list operation is succesfull or not
    })

    .finally(function(config)   // induce a syntax error here and see what happens
    {
        // It is OK not to take any action here because it would be
        // clear to the user if the list operation is succesfull or not
    });


});
//end controller
```

Ok, fixed some minor errors but now I'm getting a 404 file not found error

```
http://localhost:8080/students
```

When I visit the link in my browser I get the array displayed but the webpage is giving me;

[404 Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoVme.png)

Changing the angular.js version fixed the 404, I had the min version 1.4.8 before

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: are you getting any error for that, check network tab on dev console of browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController"> 

  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in myArray">
      <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.age }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive.

The `ng-repeat` directive repeats a set of HTML, a given number of times.

The set of HTML will be repeated once per item in a collection.

The collection must be an `array` or an `object`.

**Syntax :**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myArray"></div>
```

Answer as per your requirement :

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController"> 
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in myArray">
      <td>{{::item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{::item.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

As far as the second problem you encountered, it looks like the url you passed into the ajax call was invalid.

`404` code means that the server was unable to find the files you were looking for via `GET` or `POST` request.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/recipeWS/recipes is the correct url but I'm still getting 404 error

Comment: @user3121518 but as per your error snippet `http://i.stack.imgur.com/VoVme.png` the requesting url is different.

Comment: As per your updated question i think issue has been resolved. If you think this question will be benefitial for you as well as for others please mark it as correct.